# Wordpress in Docker doesn’t connect to the Internet

Tags: wordpress, docker

My wordpress inside a container doesn’t connect to the Internet, so if I i.e. do an action like install a plugin, I receive an error like:

> “Installation failed: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be
>   wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you
>   continue to have problems, please try the support forums.”.

Cam someone help me? I think it need some network options… I used docker instead of docker-compose, and run the instances with the following commands:

```
docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.7

docker run --name wordpress --link mysql -p 80:80 -d wordpress
```

It works, but wordpress don’t reach Internet.
I have a Proxy configured inside Docker, if it can be useful.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the docker engine uses a proxy server, the following flag may solve the problem:

```
--network=host
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I see this error:

_Error response from daemon: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior._

So I think it isn't viable.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: please remove this flag: `--link mysql`

Comment: No, I need that flag, I want to use that particular DB in another container. I need another solution, if it exists. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You are using port mapping on mysql machine, hence the wordpress machine can connect to mysql container. you don't need --link flag

Comment: But if I don't link the container, how can wordpress connect to the other container with mysql inside? Have I to run again the installation phase?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Worpress connects to port 3306 of host which is mapped to the port 3306 of the mysql container. if you previously configured the wordpress mysql hostname to localhost there is no need to rerun the installation phase. also take a look  at https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: No, it doesn't work :(. Now I receive the error _WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode_, so I can't connect to the web page...